# What does cue lots of () mean?

Tags: word-meaning

Cue lots of people, cue lots of smiles and so on. What does the word "cue" mean in these sentences?

Comment: As the definition in [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/cue).

Answer (score 2):

A "cue" in this context is a *prompt*, and usually used in the context of theatre or television production. For example, an actor or presenter's lines may be written on a *cue card*.

Stagehands or other production staff may call for some aspect of production by saying "*cue [x]*", for example, "*cue lights!*", or "*cue music!*" These kinds of direction may also be written in production notes or on scripts.

This has also become a saying outside of this context, sometimes for humour value. For example, if someone says "cue sad music" it could be a sarcastic response to somebody telling a story that failed to evoke any pity.